# PHP get static methods

Tags: php, reflection, class-method

i want to call a class method by a var (like this):

```
$var = "read";
$params = array(...); //some parameter
if(/* MyClass has the static method $var */)
{
  echo MyClass::$var($params);
}
elseif (/* MyClass hat a non-static method $var */)
{
  $cl = new MyClass($params);
  echo $cl->$var();
}
else throw new Exception();
```

i read in the php-manual how to get the function-members of a class (get_class_methods). but i get always every member without information if its static or not.

how can i determine  a method´s context?

thank you for your help

Comment: Note also that calling a static method from an instance variable is supported in PHP.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the class [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/reflectionclass.getmethods.php):

```
On Codepad.org: http://codepad.org/VEi5erFw
<?php

class MyClass
{
  public function func1(){}
  public static function func2(){}
}

$reflection = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');
var_dump( $reflection->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_STATIC) );
```

This will output all static functions.

Or if you want to determine whether a given function is static you can use the [`ReflectionMethod`](http://php.net/manual/class.reflectionmethod.php) class:

*On Codepad.org: http://codepad.org/2YXE7NJb*

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
  public function func1(){}
  public static function func2(){}
}

$reflection = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');

$func1 = $reflection->getMethod('func1');
$func2 = $reflection->getMethod('func2');

var_dump($func1->isStatic());
var_dump($func2->isStatic());
```

Comment: This is basically what I was going to say as well, you can use hasMethod of $func1 to determine whether or not to throw and exception

Answer (score 9):

One way I know of is to use [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php). In particular, one would use [`ReflectionClass::getMethods`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php) as such:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass("MyClass");
$staticmethods = $class->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_STATIC);
print_r($staticmethods);
```

The difficulty of this is that you need to have Reflection enabled, which it is not by default.