# PHP: A static function being used is nowhere to be found in the class definition.. How do I locate it?

Tags: php, reflection, static-methods, easyblog

I was trying to understand some PHP functions in Easyblog(a Joomla component), I came across these lines:

```
public function getDisplay(EasyBlogPost &$post)
{
    $fields = EB::fields();

    // I inject the following 4 lines in order to find where static function "fields" was defined
    $sss = new ReflectionClass('EB'); 
    var_dump($sss->getMethod('fields');
    var_dump($sss->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_STATIC));
    var_dump($sss->getMethod('init'); 

    $field = $fields->get($this->type);

    return $field->display($this, $post);
}
```

I was trying to find the definition of the static function `fields`. I was able to find the file where class `EB` is defined, the first lines looks like this:

```
class EB
{
    public static $headersLoaded = array();

    /**
     * Initializes EasyBlog's javascript framework
     *
     * @since   5.1
     * @access  public
     */
    public static function init($section = 'site')
    {
        // Determines if we should compile the javascripts on the site
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $input = $app->input;
        $compile = $input->get('compile', false, 'bool');
    ....
```

But in the file there is no such function called `fields`, and as you can see class `EB` doesn't inherit or implement any other class. I then turn to use `ReflectionClass`, but `var_dump($sss->getMethod('fields');` returns an error saying "no method fields", while `var_dump($sss->getMethod('init');` does return information about a static function(`init`) that is defined in the file. Also I tried `var_dump($sss->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_STATIC));` according to [PHP get static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299886/php-get-static-methods), but among the static function array returned, I can't find this "fields" function. I also did a in-text search for `function fields(` against the whole application, but nothing related was found.

Now this is totally beyond my understanding. SO wouldn't allow me to post here the whole file where class `EB` is defined, but can anyone explain to me why my approach fails in finding the definition? Can a static function be created dynamically during runtime? If so, how do I find it?

Comment: What is in the rest of the EB class?  Does it have a magic static [__callStatic](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) method?

Comment: did you double checked the name spaces of the file in both files ?

Comment: is there any `public function __call ` in `EB` class?

Comment: @Hamid it would be `__callStatic`